# Is $P$ dense in $X$?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Let $C[0,1]$ denote all the real-valued continuous function on $[0,1].$ Consider the normed linear space
>
> $$X = \left \{f \in C[0,1] : f \left ( \frac 1 2 \right ) = 0 \right \},$$
>
> with the sup-norm$,$ $\|f\| = \sup\ \{|f(t)| : t \in [0,1] \}.$ Show that the set
>
> $$P = \left \{f \in X : f\ \text {is a polynomial} \right \}$$
>
> is dense in $X.$

I take a basic open set $B(f,\epsilon) \cap X$ in $X,$ where $f \in X$ and $\epsilon > 0.$ Now by Stone-Weierstrass theorem there exists a sequence of polynomials in $C[0,1]$ converging uniformly to $f$ i.e. $\|f_n - f \| < \epsilon,$ for all $n \geq k.$ So if I can find an $n \geq k$ such that $f_n \left (\frac 1 2 \right ) = 0$ then the proof is complete.

How can I find such an $n$? Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hint: how about considering instead the sequence of the $f_n-f_n(0.5)$?

Comment: $\{f_n - f_n(0.5) \}$ also converges uniformly to $f$ in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Also at $0.5$ every term of the sequence vanishes.

Comment: Brilliant. Done it. Thanks @Mindlack for your help.

Comment: Yes, but the point is that $f(1/2)=0$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net use the fact that $f \left ( \frac 1 2 \right ) = 0$.

Comment: @Dbchatto67 Apologize guys! I'm totally wrong. I'll delete my misleading comments.

Comment: From a more conceptual point of view you can also argue as follows: As Banach-algebra, we have $X \cong C_0(S)$, where $S = [0,1/2)\coprod (1/2,1]$. You can then use the version of Stone-Weierstraß for locally compact spaces (see wikipedia).